# How to extract partial Graph for further Calculations in R

Tags: r, subset, igraph

I have a Dataset which looks like this:

```
library(igraph)
From <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
To <- c(NA,1,2,3,2,NA,6,7)
Value<- c(4,3,7,5,3,7,4,6)
Data <- data.frame(From,To, Value)
Network <- graph.data.frame(Data[,c("From","To")])
Network<- Network - "NA"
plot(Network)
```

I made some calculations with it which led to This Table:

```
From<- c(1,6)
Calc<- c(0.3,0.7)
Value<- c(4,7)
CalcData<- data.frame(From,Calc,Value)
```

Now I would like to have a function which subtracts the incoming Graph and calculates the Average Value of all Incoming(not just the directly incoming) Vertices, and adds them to the Table which afterward should look like this

```
From<- c(1,6)
Calc<- c(0.3,0.7)
Value<- c(4,7)
AverageValueIncoming<-  c((3+7+5+3)/4,(4+6)/2)
FinalData<- data.frame(From,Calc,Value,AverageValueIncoming)
```

Comment: Having `NA`s in `graph.data.frame()` is a bad idea.

Comment: Thats why i Directly Delete it after Creating the Graph